# What does from Sabbath to Sabbath mean in Isaiah 66:23?

Tags: isaiah, law, sabbath

Isaiah 66:23

> 23
> “And it shall be from new moon to new moon
> And from ***sabbath to sabbath***,
> All mankind will come to bow down before Me,” says the Lord.

Does this mean that mankind will come and worship before God on the Sabbath days only or he will be worshiped continuously from one Sabbath to another

How to understand the above text?

Comment: The use of "sabbath" in the Old Testament doesn't only refer to Saturday, but special days of rest (*sabbathoth*), or feasts and other holy days. For example, the Day of Atonement is a "sabbath" or feast or holy day (Leviticus 16).

Comment: Why not just a continuous time period as being as like one day, being one Sabbath, from Sabbath to Sabbath? ... Rather than weekly reoccurring?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your latter interpretive option is the most reasonable in my opinion.  It could mean from month to month and week to week or month to month and year to year depending on if sabbath in this context is weekly or yearly.  With either option all days of the week of the year would be covered.

Comment: Since the text states that _both_ options are in view (and that continually) your argument is stronger than you have actually stated. I suggest an edit.

Comment: I completely agree with @NigelJ.  This is a good answer.

Answer (score 2):

It just means that Sabbath Days and New Moons are dedicated worship days. On all other days, worship is done, per your desire and love for God, and per your need and thankfullness for blessings He gave you, etc. Worship is basically vocalizations to bless God, your own self-denial, and service to God's will for you, at the time.
The vocalizations are prayers or songs. Usually, you kneel and bow your forehead to the ground, offering your will for His, loving Him, etc. You can also stand, if in a congregation and lift your hands. Give glory to His Name and recive the Holy Spirit's truthful leading to sacrifice and serve. To worship in Spirit and truth blesses God and we always want to do that. A true Disciple of Christ, in a relationship with Jesus, will not want to worship only once, per week. They will every day, many times, out of pure love.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

> “And it shall be from new moon to new moon And from sabbath to sabbath, All mankind will come to bow down before Me,” says the Lord.

Though currently not explicitly defined as holy days, new moons are important for determining when the annual holy days occur.  ("on the seventh day of the month" etc.).

This verse is describing life during the Millennium.  It won't be only Israel that celebrates God's holy days, but all of mankind.
On every weekly sabbath and at every new moon, people will gather to worship God.

Weekly sabbaths are an obvious example of days that are holy to God (the fourth commandment), while a specific instance of an annual holy day is described explicitly in Zechariah 14:16:

> And it shall come to pass, that every one that is left of **all the nations** which came against Jerusalem shall even go up **from year to year** to worship the King, the LORD of hosts, and to **keep the feast of tabernacles**.

Notice the "*from year to year*" expression.  Like "*from new moon to new moon*" and "*from sabbath to sabbath*" it means every occurrence, not continuously all year long.
 and

Comment: There is no mention of, or allusion to, a thousand year period in the text.

Comment: @Nigel, nor is there any mention a few verses earlier that "_And his feet shall stand in that day upon the mount of Olives_" refers to Jesus.  Isaiah and Zechariah are talking about the Day of the Lord and the period following it, which Christians usually interpret as the beginning of the Millennium.

Comment: @Nigel, is your objection simply to the word "Millennium"?  Would using terms like "Paradise", "Kingdom of God on Earth", or "HaOlam HaBa" be acceptable?

Comment: Thx for bringing up the yearly Jerusalem journey to keep the Feast of Tabernacles. I wonder if the big picture is that: on new-moon and sabbaths days "All mankind will come to bow down before Me", at their local worship place, and once every year they will travel to Jerusalem to worship God there.

Answer (score 0):

It shows that the sabbath day worship (4th commandment) is a perpetual or eternal covenant between God and his people. God created the world in six days. On the seventh day he rested from all work (not because he was tired), blessed the day and sanctified it.
When the Israelites crossed the Red sea during their exodus from Egypt  towards Canaan God commanded them to start observing the sabbath by the way they collected and ate manna. Later when God gave Moses the 10 commandments keeping the sabbath day was the 4th commandment. This commandment was so serious  in that the punishment for breaking the sabbath was the same as someone who had committed murder.
After the second coming  of Jesus We will still be worshipping God in the new heaven and new earth on the sabbath days.(isaiah 66:23). Jesus in Matthew 24:20 hinted at this too when he gave his disciples the signs of the endtimes by telling them "to pray so that their flight don't take place on the sabbath day".
Let us all try as much as possible to keep God commandments especially the sabbath. We are saved by the grace of God through faith in jesus christ. However, Faith without works is dead. Jesus said "if you love me keep my commandments" Paul in Romans 3:31 says "Do we, then,abolish law by means of our faith? Not at all! On the contrary we uphold law". The sabbath worship according to the bible begins Friday at sunset and ends at Saturday at sunset"
https://youtu.be/kOjqwRGU4BQ?si=RMXADgoY0LFr0VI_

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).